# SQL duplicate counting headache

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a problem that I’m not sure how to overcome and would really appreciate some direction.

Example data

```
Device  Project     status
a111    101     Ready
a222    102     Finished
a333    103     Ready
a444    104     Ready
a555    105     Ready
a111    106     Started
a111    107     Ready
a555    108     Started
```

I’m looking for a way to count the number of devices at ‘Ready’ status. However, when it comes to ‘Ready’ I only want to count it once AND don’t count it if that device has a status of anything other than ‘Ready’ in another project

Logic
If ready in one or multiple projects = count once
If ready in one but has a different status in any other project = do not count

Correct result should show only 2 as 'Ready'; 'a333' and 'a444'.

```
SELECT
'Ready' AS Header
, status
, count(distinct device)
FROM my_table
WHERE
project BETWEEN'101' AND '110' 
GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use such a [`SQL Select statement`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f582/1) with `HAVING` clause :

```
select device  
  from tab 
 group by device
 having sum(case when status = 'Ready' then 1 else 0 end ) =  count(device);

 DEVICE
 ------
 a444
 a333
```

Answer (score 0):

If you devices all of whose status are ready, then one approach uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select device
from my_table t
group by device
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'Ready';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.device = t.device and t1.status <> 'Ready');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think table subtraction would be a good technique in this case.  First select using distinct:

```
select distinct(device)
  from my_table
  where status= 'Ready'
Minus
select distinct(device)
  from my_table
  where status <> 'Ready'
;
```